# Why is it okay to have a space in a `let` statement?

Tags: history-of

In my `~/.vimrc` if I write `set tabstop = 2`, it will be a syntax error:

```
set tabstop = 2 " E521: Number required after =: tabstop =
set tabstop=2   " no errors
```

But I can write `let @/ = ""`

```
let @/ = "" " no errors
let @/=""   " no errors
```

Why are they different?

Note: Reading the help menu for both `:h let` and `:h set` you can find examples using the proper syntax; however, I'm still curious why they are different.

Comment: Presumably as a hangover from the original `vi`, which has a `set` command, but not a `let`.

Comment: Are you aware of any documentation or mailing list files where this is mentioned?

Comment: what? That original vi doesn't have a let? You can find the documentation (and vi itself)  at http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/ex.html

Comment: I meant: have you come across folks discussing the sytnax of `let` for `vim`? It seems strange that they would choose to have `let foo = 42` be valid when `set foo = 42` is invalid. Does my question make sense?

Comment: actually, it doesn't seem strange at all. What's the point of sticking to an older command's limitations when designing a new command? It's a chance for a do-over, and it seems that they have done very well with `let`.

Comment: I agree that adding spaces between operators is a better choice for readability. The intention of my question isn't to argue for or against putting spaces between operators. The intention is to find some historical evidence/discussion behind the decision. For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41783001/2909897) asks about why the order of two similar methods arguments was switched. It turns out the reasons are similar to what you're saying; however, the answer gave a richer historical account which I find interesting.

Comment: This will take some digging. It looks like `let` was added between 4.6 and 5. The oldest post on the vim-announce mailing list, archived on Yahoo, simply mentions the addition of `let` to 5's alpha: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vimannounce/conversations/messages/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                                                :set-args E487 E521
:se[t] {option}={value}         or
:se[t] {option}:{value}
                        Set string or number option to {value}.
                        For numeric options the value can be given in decimal,
                        hex (preceded with 0x) or octal (preceded with '0').
                        The old value can be inserted by typing 'wildchar' (by
                        default this is a <Tab> or CTRL-E if 'compatible' is
                        set).  See cmdline-completion.
                        White space between {option} and '=' is allowed and
                        will be ignored.  White space between '=' and {value}
                        is not allowed.
```

See the last two sentences. `let` does not have this limitation.

When you `set` a string with `set option = value`, Vim does not use quotes, so  how would it know if you mean

- `"value"` or
- `" value"`?